# Send html as value to textarea

Tags: javascript, html, calculated-field

I have a textbox where I put info to get new info based on that search using the folling html & script:

HTML:

```
<input name="line" placeholder="Line" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { calculate(); return false; }" style="width:40px;" type="textbox">
<input value="Reset" type="reset">
<input id="call" placeholder="Entrepreneur" style="width:95px;" type="textbox">
<input id="number" placeholder="Phonenumber" style="width:110px;" type="textbox">
```

SCRIPT:

```
function calculate() {
  var line = document.buss.line.value;
  var ent;
  var num;

  switch(line) {
    case "12":
    case "27":
    case "30":
    <-- a lot of cases -->
      ent = "Entrepreneur";
      num = "Phonenumber";
      break;
    case "42":
    case "63":
    case "69":
    <-- a lot of cases -->
    ent = "Entrepreneur";
    num = "Number";
    break;      
    default:
  }
    document.buss.call.value = ent;
    document.buss.number.value = num;
}
```

All this works perfect but now I needed to put in some new information in a textarea but I can not get it to print the way I want. What I want is for the information to incude  and 
 but right now it prints this as text instead of html, is there a way to change this? also is there a way to print it directly to the page instead of having a lot of textboxes and textarea?

HTML:

```
<input name="line" placeholder="Line" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { calculate(); return false; }" style="width:40px;" type="textbox">
<input value="Reset" type="reset">
<input id="call" placeholder="Entrepreneur" style="width:114px;" type="textbox">
<input id="number" placeholder="Number" style="width:90px;" type="textbox">
<textarea id="stop" placeholder="Stop" style="width:300px; height:650px"></textarea>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function calculate() {
  var line = document.buss.line.value;
  var ent;
  var num;
  var stop;

  switch(line) {
    case "1":
      ent = "Entrepreneur";
      num = "Number";
      stop = "<b>stop1</b><br>stop2<br>stop3<br><b>stop4</b>";
      break;
    case "2":
      ent = "Entrepreneur";
      num = "Number";
      stop = "<b>stop1</b><br>stop2<br>stop3<br><b>stop4</b>";
      break;
    default:
  }
    document.buss.call.value = ent;
    document.buss.number.value = num;
    document.buss.stop.value = stop;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render html inside a Textarea object.
If you dont need the text to be editable, you can replace the inputs and textarea with div ou span tags, and replace it's content.

Example:

If you replace this:

```
<textarea id="stop" placeholder="Stop" style="width:300px; height:650px"></textarea>
```

With this:

```
<div id="stop" style="width:300px; height:650px">Stop</div>
```

And replace this:

```
document.buss.stop.value = stop;
```

With this:

```
document.getElementById('stop').innerHTML = stop;
```

The html is rendered.

To make the Reset Button work, you will need to add a reset function. This should do the trick:

```
<input onclick="resetHtml()" value="Reset" type="reset">

function resetHtml() {
    document.getElementById('stop').innerHTML = "Stop";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to empty this information with the <input value="Reset" type="reset"> as well?

Comment: Not directly, you will need to add an click event to do this job. I will add a code example to the answer.

Comment: When there is "to much" information sent to the div it goes behind other things instead of being scrollable and boing inside 650px height like it was when it was for example textarea. Is that fixable as well?

Comment: Sure, just add an overflow: scroll; in the css properties of the div.
<div id="stop" style="width:300px; height:650px; overflow: scroll;">